# HOw can i remove the uiview background black color

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that i set the one image as background for uiview like below

```
projectview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 640, 700)];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(projectview.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"board.png"] drawInRect:projectview.bounds];
UIImage *lblviewimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

projectview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:lblviewimage];
[self.view addSubview:projectview];
```

It's working fine in simulator.But when i run this one in device,that image is added to uiview and the remaining space other than that image will be appeared as black.So please tell me how can i remove that black color.

Comment: projectview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; or any color you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use     `projectview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Or if you want to display the default white color then write

`projectview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Now,

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 640, 700)];
[projectview addSubView:imageview];
```

Dont set the background of the UIView, add another imageView on it and set the frame accordingly.

Comment: Hello,i need that image as background color for uiview.And remain space of uiview otherthan that image as clearcolor.I don't want to self.view background color.

Comment: Then create an imageView and add the image on the full frame of the projectView ... That is your imageView would have imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 640, 700)];

Comment: Iam performing the animation from left to right.If i add imageview to view then in that animation time that imageview is not moving and another imageview will be overwritten.SO i need to set the background for uiview.

Comment: U did not mention the animation condition earlier so please clarify your question first and state your conditions first . Thanks :)

Comment: First iam doing the animation.In that animation i removing the all views and again add all views.In that time i need to add view with image background.If i add uiimageview to view then that imageview will be added two times.

Comment: How about adding your UIImageView globally for all the views so whenever any of the views will be loaded the imageview would be there 2 ... is that wat u want to achieve rite ?